# Subalgebra Definition

Tags: definition, algebras

If A is an algebra over a field K, and B is a subalgebra, must B be an algebra over K or can it also be an algebra over some subfield of K?

For example, if you take $\mathbb{R}$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, would it be correct to call $\mathbb{Q}$ a subalgebra, since it is an algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$? I would think not, but it seems to satify all the axioms.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed under scalar multiplication by a non-rational element in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think the problem arises from sloppy, albeit standard, usage. One should really speak of $A$ as a "$K$-algebra", and of $B$ as a "$K$-subalgebra" of $A$. This is normally dropped and inferred from context, but you see the problems it can cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the same reason it is not sensible to call a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ which is a $\Bbb Q$ vector space an "subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Lots of stuff would break down, most obviously dimension theorems.

For both vector $F$ vector spaces and $F$-algebras, it's implied that the subobjects inherit the same operation of scaling with elements of $F$.

Comment: Should being closed under multiplication by an element in K be an axiom for a subalgebra? I expect it to be but it isn't on my list, the example I gave was totally consistent with my definition of subalgebra.

Comment: Yes, it should definitely be in a complete list of axioms. Does your list include "the subset is a vector subspace"?

Comment: No, I guess it's just a mistake then.